# Qt: how to import dll without header and lib files

Tags: c++, qt, dll

I would like to include a dll from this website http://projnet.codeplex.com/  But it only provides a dll file and a xml file, no header file or lib file is included. Is it possible to import the dll using something like

```
QLibrary geolib("ProjNet.dll");
geolib.load();
```

If it works (in this case geolib.isloaded is true) then how do I use it in Qt?

Thanks very much!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a managed DLL, for the .net framework, which explains why it has no header file. You won't be able to use it directly. You'll need to wrap it. For instance with COM or as a mixed mode C++/CLI DLL.

Answer (score 0):

You can use in such a way only exported functions (for this you need to know the function's name and prototype). After you load dll you should invoke [resolve](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qlibrary.html#resolve) method. For example, you want to use exported function *foo* from MyModule.dll:

```
extern "C" Q_DECL_EXPORT void foo(int a)
```

You need to create a prototype:

```
typedef void (*MyProto)(int)
```

And than resolve it:

```
QLibrary myDll("MyModule.dll");
if (myDll.load())
{
    MyProto mp = reinterpret_cast<MyProro>(myDll.resolve("foo"));
}
```

Unfortunately, ProjNet.dll has no exports.

Comment: It's not so much that it has no exports, it's more that it's completely the wrong type of thing. It exports plenty of funcionality.

Comment: My answer was only about using dll functionality directly without any wrappers. What do you mean by "... it's completely the wrong type of thing"?

Comment: I mean that `QLibrary` is for unmanaged code, and that `ProjNet.dll` is a managed DLL, something entirely different